# Lambda function to grab numbers from a specific string

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas, substring

Is there a way to create a function that searches an entire dataframe for a string, when it finds said string then pulls the proceeding numbers from it?

ex dataframe:

```
1                       2                               3                       4 
6/9/2020 1 Per Page  IRES MLS  : 91 PRICE: $59,900    Beautiful Views Sold   Total Concession: $2000
6/9/2020 1 Per Page  IRES MLS : 906 PRICE: $350,000   Fast Seller!           Total Concession: $5029
6/9/2020 1 Per Page  IRES MLS : 908 PRICE: $360,000   Total Concession: $9000
```

I was able to create a function which tells if that string exists or not and returns a boolean value

```
#searches the dataframe for the words Total Concession and returns if True
df['Concession'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains('Total Concession', regex=True).any(), axis=1)
```

Total Concession doesn't have one column within the created dataframe, it's found within different columns in the dataframe. I was wondering if there was a way to do so it returns this.

```
Concession
2000
5029
9000
```

Comment: the data just shared, is it just one column? is it safe to assume then that your dataframe has only one column?

Comment: no, the dataframe has multiple columns. The ** separates them and creates a new column based on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because what you are looking for is at the tail end of each column. Concat all the string columns into a column named `text` using the `.join()` method

One line of code

```
df['text'] = df.apply(''.join, axis=1).str.split('[$]').str[-1]
```

Alternatively, if wanted to use Regex can try

```
#df['text'] = df.apply(''.join, axis=1).str.extract('((?<=Concession:).*$)')#Use positive look ahead.Basically anything after Concession:
#df['text']=df['text'].str.replace('$','')#Replace $ with a white space




        1                                           2  \
0  6/9/2020   1 Per Page  IRES MLS  : 91 PRICE: $59,900   
1  6/9/2020  1 Per Page  IRES MLS : 906 PRICE: $350,000   
2  6/9/2020  1 Per Page  IRES MLS : 908 PRICE: $360,000   

                         3                        4  \
0     Beautiful Views Sold  Total Concession: $2000   
1             Fast Seller!  Total Concession: $5029   
2  Total Concession: $9000  Total Concession: $9000   

                                                text concession  
0  6/9/20201 Per Page  IRES MLS  : 91 PRICE: $59,...       2000  
1  6/9/20201 Per Page  IRES MLS : 906 PRICE: $350...       5029  
2  6/9/20201 Per Page  IRES MLS : 908 PRICE: $360...       9000
```

Comment: apologies, my example dataframe was not accurate, there are separate columns, and some of them contain the text I'm searching for, but it's inconsitant.

Comment: Was this helpful?

Comment: this is definitely getting me on the right track. It split correctly, but now I need to remove some of the trailing strings. This wasn't part of my original question though. My actual dataframe is too big to put as a minimally reproducible example so this does indeed answer the question posed. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is one way about it; the caveat is that there is only one column that can have total concession - you may have to reword your question, if you feel more than one column can contain total concession

```
import re
def extract(text_box):

    #extract text that has Total Concession
    for entry in text_box:
        if entry is None:
            continue
        if "Total Concession" in entry:
            text = entry
    match = re.search("(?<=Total Concession:).*", text)
    res = match.group(0).strip().strip("$")

    return res
```

Apply function :

```
df['extract'] = [extract(lst) for lst in df.to_numpy()]

1   2   3   4   extract
0   6/9/2020 1 Per Page IRES MLS    : 91 PRICE: $59,900 Beautiful Views Sold Total Concession: $2000    2000
1   6/9/2020 1 Per Page IRES MLS : 906 PRICE: $350,000  Fast Seller!    Total Concession: $5029 5029
2   6/9/2020 1 Per Page IRES MLS : 908 PRICE: $360,000  Total Concession: $9000 None    9000
```

Comment: got this as an error unfortunately, ```UnboundLocalError: local variable 'text' referenced before assignment```

Answer (score 0):

## Use [pandas.Series.str.findall](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html#pandas-series-str-findall) with a positive lookbehind:

- `'(?<= \$)[\d,]+`

  - [image]
  - This will extract the match from anywhere in the string.

```py
import pandas as pd

# setup dataframe
data = {'Date': ['6/9/2020', '6/9/2020', '6/9/2020'],
        'Price': ['1 Per Page  IRES MLS  : 91 PRICE: $59,900', '1 Per Page  IRES MLS : 906 PRICE: $350,000', '1 Per Page  IRES MLS : 908 PRICE: $360,000'],
        'Description': ['Beautiful Views Sold', 'Fast Seller!', ''],
        'Total Concession': ['Total Concession: $2000', 'Total Concession: $5029', 'Total Concession: $9000']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

       Date                                       Price           Description         Total Concession
0  6/9/2020   1 Per Page  IRES MLS  : 91 PRICE: $59,900  Beautiful Views Sold  Total Concession: $2000
1  6/9/2020  1 Per Page  IRES MLS : 906 PRICE: $350,000          Fast Seller!  Total Concession: $5029
2  6/9/2020  1 Per Page  IRES MLS : 908 PRICE: $360,000                        Total Concession: $9000

# extract numbers from columns
for c in df.columns:
    df[f'extracted {c}'] = df[c].str.findall('(?<= \$)[\d,]+').explode().str.replace(',', '')

# columns with no match, like Description, will be all NaN, so drop them
df.dropna(axis=1, inplace=True, how='all')

# output
       Date                                       Price           Description         Total Concession extracted Price extracted Total Concession
0  6/9/2020    1 Per Page $59,798 IRES MLS  : 91 PRICE:  Beautiful Views Sold  Total Concession: $2000           59798                       2000
1  6/9/2020  1 Per Page  IRES MLS : 906 PRICE: $350,000          Fast Seller!  Total Concession: $5029          350000                       5029
2  6/9/2020  1 Per Page  IRES MLS : 908 PRICE: $360,000                        Total Concession: $9000          360000                       9000

# drop or rename other columns as needed
```

## Only Total Concession

- `'(?<=Total Concession: \$)[\d,]+'`

  - [image]
  - This will extract only numbers preceded by `'Total Concession: $'`

```py
for c in df.columns:
    df[f'extracted {c}'] = df[c].str.findall('(?<=Total Concession: \$)[\d,]+').explode().str.replace(',', '')

df.dropna(axis=1, inplace=True, how='all')

# output
       Date                                       Price           Description         Total Concession extracted Total Concession
0  6/9/2020   1 Per Page  IRES MLS  : 91 PRICE: $59,900  Beautiful Views Sold  Total Concession: $2000                       2000
1  6/9/2020  1 Per Page  IRES MLS : 906 PRICE: $350,000          Fast Seller!  Total Concession: $5029                       5029
2  6/9/2020  1 Per Page  IRES MLS : 908 PRICE: $360,000                        Total Concession: $9000                       9000
```

## Robust Example

```py
# setup dataframe
data = {'Date': ['6/9/2020', '6/9/2020', '6/9/2020'],
        'Price': ['1 Per Page  IRES MLS  : 91 PRICE: $59,900', '1 Per Page  IRES MLS : 906 PRICE: $350,000', '1 Per Page  IRES MLS : 908 PRICE: $360,000'],
        'Description': ['Beautiful Views Sold', 'Fast Seller!', ''],
        'Total Concession': ['Nothing to see here', 'Total Concession: $5029', 'Total Concession: $9000'],
        'Test1': ['A bunch Total Concession: $6,399 of random stuff', 'stuff1', 'stuff2']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

       Date                                       Price           Description         Total Concession                                             Test1
0  6/9/2020   1 Per Page  IRES MLS  : 91 PRICE: $59,900  Beautiful Views Sold      Nothing to see here  A bunch Total Concession: $6,399 of random stuff
1  6/9/2020  1 Per Page  IRES MLS : 906 PRICE: $350,000          Fast Seller!  Total Concession: $5029                                            stuff1
2  6/9/2020  1 Per Page  IRES MLS : 908 PRICE: $360,000                        Total Concession: $9000                                            stuff2


for c in df.columns:
    df[f'extracted {c}'] = df[c].str.findall('(?<=Total Concession: \$)[\d,]+').explode().str.replace(',', '')

df.dropna(axis=1, inplace=True, how='all')


# list of all extracted columns
extracted_columns = [x for x in df.columns if 'extracted' in x]

# sum all extracted columns
df['all concessions'] = df[extracted_columns].astype(float).sum(axis=1)

# drop the extracted columns
df.drop(columns=extracted_columns, inplace=True)

# print df
       Date                                       Price           Description         Total Concession                                             Test1  all concessions
0  6/9/2020   1 Per Page  IRES MLS  : 91 PRICE: $59,900  Beautiful Views Sold      Nothing to see here  A bunch Total Concession: $6,399 of random stuff           6399.0
1  6/9/2020  1 Per Page  IRES MLS : 906 PRICE: $350,000          Fast Seller!  Total Concession: $5029                                            stuff1           5029.0
2  6/9/2020  1 Per Page  IRES MLS : 908 PRICE: $360,000                        Total Concession: $9000                                            stuff2           9000.0
```

Comment: Unfortunately ```Total Concession``` is not located in one column, it's found throughout the dataframe

Comment: @Taylor it will find the match in any column. See the robust example for proof.

Comment: I received the error ```ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis```, tried to do ```df = df[~df.index.duplicated()]``` but still gave me that error

Comment: @Taylor This is based on your example. `df.reset_index` then run my code.